# Why JavaScript closures will not work with predefined function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures, state

Let's say I have this JavaScript closure:

```
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();
```

and I call `add` three times:

```
add();
add();
add();
```

Now the counter in the self-invoking function is equal to 3.  But why will the above not increment counter or keep the parent function's scope alive if the self-invoking function was instead a predefined or even an anonymous function?

By predefined function i mean standard function declaration,something like this:

```
function testingjsclosure()
{
   var counter = 0;
   return function(){return counter += 1;}
}
add = testingjsclosure();
```

Comment: are you sure you are testing the right way, it is working for me even as predefined function.

Comment: It works for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/sj3nk655/

Comment: im not saying if the i can execute the second code(predefined function example), im trying to figure why closures only work with self-invoking functions and not functions of other types like predefined and anonymous functions.

Comment: The predefined function works for me and creates a closure just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ej8efxe2/

Comment: jfriend00 - wierd in the w3 javascript editor, it displays nothing :http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter1

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the above will not increment counter or keep the parent function's scope alive" or by "if the self-invoking function was instead a predefined or even an anonymous function". Please rephrase.

Comment: There's no closure in your w3 script.  You aren't returning a function from `add()` so it's just a normal function who's local variables are garbage collected as soon as the function finishes and thus it's done.  Each successive call to `add()` just runs it over again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no self-invoking function here.

The expression

```
function () { var counter = 0; return ...; }
```

has as value a function that has local state and returns a certain value. So

```
var add = (function () { var counter = 0; return ...; })();
```

calls it and assigns the returned value to `add`. That value is

```
function () {return counter += 1;}
```

which is a function that increments and returns that particular local variable. So calling `add` calls that function and so increments and returns that particular local variable.

But

```
add = testingjsclosure();
```

calls testingjsclosure with no arguments and assigns its return value to add.

`function(){ ... }` is like quote marks around an expression `...` in that that expression is not evaluated until the variable that has the value of the function expression is called.

Whereas

```
function testingjsclosure() { ...}
```

is like writing

```
var testingjsclosure = function() { ...}
```